# Connecting Bot Framework v4 bot to a Power Virtual Agent bot in nodejs

Tags: node.js, botframework

I have existing Bot Framework v4 Virtual Assistant bot Ref: [BF VA](https://microsoft.github.io/botframework-solutions/overview/virtual-assistant-solution/)

I would like to Leverage "Power virtual agents" to build the bots and, have a way to connect to PVA bot from existing BF Virtual Assistant. Any suggestion on how can we achieve in Javascript BF SDK?

Idea is that BF bot should connect to PVA bot and, get the response back to user User will never know that response was actually from PVA bot. User will keep chatting with BF VA bot as normal.

Simple googling I came across [Connector App but, its in C#](https://microsoft.github.io/botframework-solutions/overview/virtual-assistant-solution/).
Has anyone tried this before? Any suggestions ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Please reference the Bot Framework [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/skill-pva?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) that discusses this option. There is additional information made available from the PVA team, located [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-virtual-agents/configuration-add-skills#configure-a-skill-for-use-in-power-virtual-agents).

Hope of help!